# Post in ionic 3, cannot post

Tags: angular, post, ionic3, httpclient, postdata

I am trying to send a POST request with HttpClient Angular to a server. I have error in code:

file *.ts

```
import {  HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

public link ='http://opencart-ir.com/test/json.php';
public postData(){
  let postData = new FormData();
  postData.append('parentid','0');
  this.http.post(this.link,this.postData)
  .subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log("Oooops!");
    });
}
```

file *.html

```
<button (click)="postData()">Post</button>
```

file json.php

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $data= array(
    'get' => $_GET,
    'post' => $_POST
  );
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

run massage in console

```
{get: Array(0), post: Array(0)}
  get: []
  post: []
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: cannot post  postData to server 
Nothing data to server 
But im send postData.append('parentid','0');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reffering to the function postData instead of the variable it should be `postData` instead of `this.postData`:

```
 this.http.post(this.link, postData).subscribe(data =>{
   console.log(data);
 }, error => {
   console.log("Oooops!");
 });
```